# Next.js Route Handler when deployed on Vercel with Firestore doesn't show on firebase console the added data only in local mode

Tags: firebase, vercel, next.js13

When using Next.js 14 with Firebase, I encountered an issue with the POST method in my client-side code. The goal is to send form data to a route handler. On the route handler, I extract the data from the request body and call a function called CreateMundiLead, which uses Firebase's setDoc method to add the information to the database.

In my local development environment, I can see the data being added to Firebase and successfully fetch and display it on the client side using a GET method. However, when deploying the app on Vercel, the POST method does not add the data to Firebase. Although I can still fetch and display the data on the client side, it does not appear in the Firebase console.

I have implemented a middleware to handle requests, but it doesn't seem to resolve this specific issue. The problem only occurs in the deployed version, while everything works as expected in the local development mode.

To summarize, my problem lies in not being able to see the data added to Firebase when using the POST method after deploying the app, despite successfully retrieving and displaying the data on the client side.

I tried to send form data from the client side using the POST method to a route handler in a Next.js 14 with Firebase web app. I expected the data to be successfully added to the Firebase database, both in my local development environment and when the app is deployed on Vercel. Additionally, I expected to be able to fetch and display the added data correctly on the client side. However, despite seeing the data being added and fetched successfully in the local development mode, I encountered issues after deploying the app. The data added using the POST method was not visible in the Firebase console, although I could still fetch and display it on the client side.